# Difference between "Windows Phone HTML5 App" and "Javascript Windows Store Project"

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Could everyone tell me what is the difference between 
"Windows Phone HTML5 App" (under new project -> Windows Phone) and 
"Javascript Windows Store Project" (under new project -> Other Languages -> JavaScript -> Windows Store)?

In a HTML5 project there is a possibility to debug on device but in a "Javascript Windows Store Project" project you cannot. Is there also a possibility to debug on device on a Javascript project?

Thanks

Comment: Dunno but you must have all the other differences between Mobile and Win 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **Windows Phone HTML5 app** project only runs on **Windows Phone** and is an app using a WebBrowser control hosting the HTML. No native support from the underlying OS, just the browser displaying HTML pages. You can tie JavaScript methods to C#, it's possible to debug this.

The **Windows Store** project only runs on **Windows 8** as a "Metro" or "Modern UI" app. The JavaScript is hosted in the WinRT runtime and has integration with many parts of the OS.

These two templates are not interchangeable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I made a reference to winjs in a "Windows Phone HTML5 app"? Or is there another js library to access windows phone components?

Comment: WinJS is not available on the Phone. I've no real experience using JS in Windows Phone apps, but there are libraries out there. Look at this article, maybe it's a good starting point for you: [How to create HTML5 apps on Windows Phone with PhoneGap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh771462.aspx)